# Xamarin MonoAndroid Azure mobile service InsertAsync

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Xamarin for Android and have added the azure mobile services componenet.

I'm trying to create the todo list application like (https://github.com/xamarin/azure-mobile-services)

I connect to the mobile service like this:

```
public static string mobileServiceUrl = "http://MyMoblieService.azure-mobile.net/.azure-mobile.net/";
public static string mobileServiceAppKey = "MyAppKey";

private static readonly MobileServiceClient MobileService =
            new MobileServiceClient(mobileServiceUrl, mobileServiceAppKey);

this.adapter = new TodoAdapter(MobileService.GetTable<Item>(), this);
```

I use the adapte Insert function to insert data into the table

```
   public void Insert(Item item)
   {
    IsUpdating = true;
    this.items.Add(item);
    NotifyDataSetChanged();

    this.table.InsertAsync(item).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            this.items.Remove(item);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        IsUpdating = false;
    }, scheduler);
}
```

and everytime I get `t.IsFaulted = true`, while debuging when I dig in t.Exception I find `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException`

I would be glad to supply the rest of the code if needed.

**Edited**
The only way I could get the exception level is by getting the details from the watch window while debugging.
The exception has 2 attributes: Request&Response
The request:
-       Request {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ServiceFilterRequest}    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ServiceFilterRequest
        Accept  "application/json"  string
        Content "{\"text\": \"tyu\", \"complete\": false}"  string
        ContentType "application/json"  string
-       Headers Count=2 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
-       Items   {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[2]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[]
-       [0] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID"    string
        Value   "17b22eec-edd2-4a15-a37f-d4c5d87e4e8e"  string
+       Non-public members
-       [1] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "X-ZUMO-APPLICATION"    string
        Value   "FmlVNVhdQhNEAIZZVptKhxlQNuJrlq37"  string
+       Non-public members
+       Raw View
        Method  "POST"  string
-       Uri {System.Uri}    System.Uri
        AbsolutePath    "/.azure-mobile.net/tables/Item"    string
        AbsoluteUri 
        Authority   "ichange.azure-mobile.net"  string
        DnsSafeHost "ichange.azure-mobile.net"  string
        Fragment    ""  string
        Host    "ichange.azure-mobile.net"  string
        HostNameType    System.UriHostNameType.Dns  System.UriHostNameType
        IsAbsoluteUri   true    bool
        IsDefaultPort   true    bool
        IsFile  false   bool
        IsLoopback  false   bool
        IsUnc   false   bool
        LocalPath   "/.azure-mobile.net/tables/Item"    string
        OriginalString
        PathAndQuery    "/.azure-mobile.net/tables/Item"    string
        Port    80  int
        Query   ""  string
        Scheme  "http"  string
+       Segments    {string[4]} string[]
        UserEscaped false   bool
        UserInfo    ""  string
+       Static members
+       Non-public members
        Static members

The response
-       Response    {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ServiceFilterResponse}   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ServiceFilterResponse
        Content "{\"code\":404,\"error\":\"Error: Not Found\"}" string
        ContentType "application/json"  string
-       Headers Count=8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
-       Items   {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[8]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[]
-       [0] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "Cache-Control" string
        Value   "no-cache"  string
+       Non-public members
-       [1] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "Content-Length"    string
        Value   "39"    string
+       Non-public members
-       [2] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "Content-Type"  string
        Value   "application/json"  string
+       Non-public members
-       [3] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "Server"    string
        Value   "Microsoft-IIS/8.0" string
+       Non-public members
-       [4] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "Set-Cookie"    string
        Value   "ARRAffinity=3041b7170f63e41156a1ff0b65518583e91f68d4f90a680a7750bd8d12f209e0;Path=/;Domain=ichange.a…" string
+       Non-public members
-       [5] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "x-zumo-version"    string
        Value   "Zumo.Main.0.1.6.3017.Runtime"  string
+       Non-public members
-       [6] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "X-Powered-By"  string
        Value   "ASP.NET"   string
+       Non-public members
-       [7] {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
        Key "Date"  string
        Value   "Thu, 27 Jun 2013 18:23:56 GMT" string
+       Non-public members
+       Raw View
        ResponseStatus  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ServiceFilterResponseStatus.ProtocolError Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ServiceFilterResponseStatus
        StatusCode  404 int
        StatusDescription   "Not Found" string

Comment: What are the details of the exception object?

Comment: @carlosfigueira I edited the questions with the details, I get in the response 404 not found

Comment: This looks strange: `string mobileServiceUrl = "http://MyMoblieService.azure-mobile.net/.azure-mobile.net/` - are you sure you have the right URL? I really doubt it should have the **./azure-mobile.net/** after the domain name...

Comment: @carlosfigueira that was the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments: the URL you're passing to the `MobileServiceClient` constructor is incorrect. The 'Not Found' response made me look in the URL which you have:

```
public static string mobileServiceUrl =
    "http://MyMoblieService.azure-mobile.net/.azure-mobile.net/";
```

And that's incorrect. It should be as shown below:

```
public static string mobileServiceUrl =
    "http://MyMoblieService.azure-mobile.net/";
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, I see you work on Mobile Services team, great!! :D Can you please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411397/loginasync-missing) if you find time? Thank you so much!