# LoginAsync missing

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I wrote an Android application that uses Azure to perform user login with Google, Twitter and Facebook; it uses `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Android.dll` and with this I'm able to do something like

```
await Client.LoginAsync(context, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
```

(in Azure I set ids and secrets to use Google, Facebook and Twitter).

Now I'm developing a Windows app (desktop app) using **Windows 7**, **VS2012** and **Framework 4.5** and I'd like to perform same login (so I can get authentication token and use it to query my sql database); I used NuGet to import `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile` package and I see referenced both *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile* and *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext*.

When I try to use `LoginAsync`, similar syntax I used in Android is missing.
According to this link http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/work-with-net-client-library/#caching in extension package there should be an extension method that lets me use

```
user = await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
```

but VS cannot see it and so I cannot use it.
I just see method

```
LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, JsonObject token)
```

but I don't need it honestly...
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

The "simplified", or "browser-based" login method is available on all supported platforms, except the full .NET Framework 4.5. That platform lacks that functionality because there are cases where it cannot display a web interface where the user can enter their credentials. For example, it can be used in a backend service (see an example at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/25/exposing-authenticated-data-from-azure-mobile-services-via-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx)). It can also be a console application, in which there’s no “native” way to display a web page. Even on project types with "native" UI components, such as WinForms or WPF, there's no "natural" way to show a login page - if the window were WPF-based, it wouldn't look natural in a WinForms app, and vice-versa.

For a specific platform, however, you can add that method as an extension method. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/27/web-based-login-on-wpf-projects-for-azure-mobile-services.aspx talks exactly about that, and it has some code showing how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, thanks a million. Tomorrow I'll check your link and try your solution. Thank you!